# App delegate in ios

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't understand what this code does:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

can somebody explain it to me please??

Comment: What exactly do you need explained? It's the same as any other method in objective-c; `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` returns a [`UIApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and `[... delegate]` returns an [`id<ApplicationDelegate>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), which is stored into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a pointer to the Application Delegate.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication]
```

returns you a pointer to your application instance (singleton instance, only one instance of that object is permitted, and it's returned by the "sharedApplication" method).

Then, "delegate" returns the delegate of this UIApplication instance, that **usually** is implemented in the AppDelegate.m and AppDelegate.h files of your application and it's of AppDelegate Class.

Answer (score 0):

Each iOS app has one application delegate. The code you ask about gives you a reference to that delegate. Please see the docs for `UIApplication delegate` and `UIApplicationDelegate` for more details.